# O que é um Vaporware?

Tags: terminologia, app

Tenho escutado o termo **Vaporware** com certa frequência. Pessoas falando que é algo não se sustenta, fogo de palha, etc.

Mas o que qualifica um **Vaporware**, exitem fatores claros para classificar um aplicativo, sistema ou `pwa` como `vaporware`?

Não sei se entendi direito o conceito da palavra, e muito menos se existem critérios sólidos para dizer que algo é ou não é um vaporware...

No mundo do desenvolvimento quando e como algo vira um **Vaporware**?

Comment: Complementei minha resposta com o que define algo como vaporware e o que não define. Poderia verificar?

Comment: Não vejo como vapor poderia ter critério sólidos... hahahaha

Comment: @fernandosavio mesmo sendo  vapor, ainda ocupa  espaço  

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Não existe uma regra específica para qualificar um produto como Vaporware, e eu vou explicar o porquê.

Vamos começar com sua definição: *vaporware* é aquele lançamento nunca lançado. Normalmente você nunca associa um aplicativo à um Vaporware porque o mesmo **nem existe**, ou se existe, ficou travado num beta eterno e nunca mais saiu da fase de homologação (isso se teve homologação).

Normalmente é qualificado como *Vaporware* quando é anunciado mas sequer entrou em desenvolvimento. É aquela promessa de algo que nunca veio à tona. Muitas vezes fazem um *hype* enorme para promover a empresa ou gerar campanha, e anunciam o produto para um tempo bem longo. Mas quando dá esse tempo, nem sequer criaram um repositório para o projeto.

> Não sei se entendi direito o conceito da palavra e muito menos se existem critérios sólidos para dizer que algo é ou não é um vaporware...

Esse termo é mais algo teórico do que comprovatório. Não existem regras para algo ser *vaporware* ou não. Definimos algo como "vaporwareirizado" quando se aplicamos às regras acima descritas. Você já deve ter visto alguma situação de um Vaporware barato e nem se deu conta. [O Xbox 720 é um exemplo](https://www.terra.com.br/diversao/games/plataformas/xbox-360/microsoft-apresenta-xbox-720-veja-o-que-esperar-do-console,e928e0876c3ce310VgnVCM5000009ccceb0aRCRD.html).

Vaporware não se aplica somente à softwares. Pode ser um computador, um software, ou qualquer coisa que pretende mostrar que a empresa é inovadora e sempre está pesquisando coisas novas.

Não devemos confundir "Codenome", ou "Projeto de desenvolvimento" com Vaporware. Como foi o caso do [Windows Longhorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development_of_Windows_Vista), que foi o codenome do beta do Windows Vista. A princípio, o Windows Longhorn seria seu próprio sistema operacional e já anunciado pela Microsoft, mas no final foi lançado como Windows Vista.

Projetos descontinuados podem até ser considerados *Vaporware*. Independente se a empresa anunciou que o projeto jamais será lançado, ela se deu conta de anunciar, mas nunca lançou.

Nem sempre um Vaporware vem da própria empresa. Terceiros podem anunciar por ela algo que jamais existirá.

Acredito que o termo "Vaporware" tem sido originado do mesmo termo que surgiu o "Vaporwave", um gênero musical que usa elementos psicodélicos e retrô para conduzir uma arte nostalgica e morta.

> No mundo do desenvolvimento quando e como algo vira um Vaporware?

Alguns fatores que podem classificar um produto como Vaporware é:

- Foi anunciado mas nunca lançado;
- Foi anunciado mas descontinuado;
- Foi anunciado mas seu lançamento foi bem diferente (e inferior) ao que foi anunciado, criando um produto separado do que foi anunciado (e não o real lançamento proposto).

Como descrito no segundo parágrafo, e em resumo, é aquilo que é feito campanhas, anúncios e toda a festa de lançamento de algo que jamais será lançado. Até onde sei, um *Vaporware* não é lançado, e quando o produto anunciado é realmente lançado, deixa de ser um Vaporware, e se torna somente um lançamento atrasado, ou bem atrasado.

Comment: Valeu jovem, muito explicativa sua resposta!